# What is _init in profiling result

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, profiling

I've seen a strange function (_init) in my profile results :

[image]

In the parent function there is a `uint64_t` initialization and some math operations (sum, multiply, ...).

What is this `_init` function? Is it related to that `uint64_t` init?

Edit: I am using `gcc version 8.3.0`

Comment: Identifiers starting with underscores are usually part of the internal workings of the compiler or standard library implementation, so it may help your question if you add which compiler you are using.

Answer (score 1):

`_init` is a function that gets called when a shared library is loaded. In our example, it will depend on what library you are linking against (running `ldd` against the binary should give you some hints).

As a side-note, the `_init` and `_fini` functions are obsolete now and should be replaced by `__attribute__ ((constructor))` and `__attribute__ ((destructor))`. To quote from the [documentation 5.2.1](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/miscellaneous.html):

> 5.2.1. Special functions _init and _fini (OBSOLETE/DANGEROUS)
>
> Historically there have been two special functions, _init and _fini that can be used to control constructors and destructors. However, they are obsolete, and their use can lead to unpredicatable results. Your libraries should not use these; use the function attributes constructor and destructor above instead.
>
> If you must work with old systems or code that used _init or _fini, here's how they worked. Two special functions were defined for initializing and finalizing a module: _init and _fini. If a function ``_init'' is exported in a library, then it is called when the library is first opened (via dlopen() or simply as a shared library). In a C program, this just means that you defined some function named _init. There is a corresponding function called _fini, which is called whenever a client finishes using the library (via a call dlclose() that brings its reference count to zero, or on normal exit of the program). The C prototypes for these functions are:
>
> ```
>  void _init(void);
>  void _fini(void);
> ```

Comment: I didn't used this function in my program, and if you sure about "loading shared library" part then should this function run once for every lib?